# accessing instance method from findOne in sequelize 5

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have an instance method namely `isAdmin()` of a model,but I am unable to access it directly like in sequelize 3.

Here's the snippet:

```
 BranchUser.findOne({ where: {branchUserBranchId: userid} }).then(user => {
                    console.log('user:  ',user.isAdmin());
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining the `isAdmin()` method?  Here's an example that works for me:

```
BranchUser.prototype.isAdmin = function () {
  // sample instance code here:
  if (this.adminFlag) {   
     console.log('yes, I am an admin.  thanks for asking');
  }
}
```